# how to install libmemcached for django framework in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: python, django, libmemcached

I installed libmemcached 0,37 and ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmemcached.so.2 /usr/lib/libmemcached.so.2

but when I run manage.py 
it still return
import _pylibmc
RuntimeError: pylibmc requires >= libmemcached 0.32, was compiled with 0.31

I try to install newer libmemcached,but they donot have the file libmemcached.so.2

Answer (score 15):

You just need to install these dependencies before installing `pylibmc`

```
sudo apt-get install -y libmemcached-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev python-dev build-essential

pip install pylibmc
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/2203961) is gist on Github that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You should install `python-memcached`

You can install like this,

```
sudo pip install python-memcached
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install python-memcache
```

python2.7-dev if not installed, you have to install like this,

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```

Comment: Django memcache supports two binaries python-memcached` and `pylibmc`. Opt is having issue in `pylibmc` ??